# How to upgrade sqlite database on android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I implemented a ContentProvider for my android app and it works very well but when I make some changes to the schema, the database doesn't seem to be upgraded.
I have the following code in my SQLiteOpenHelper :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Upgrading database. Existing contents will be lost. ["
        + oldVersion + "]->[" + newVersion + "]");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TUTORIALS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

If I update my app with a new schema then all my inserts fail BUT if I uninstall the old version and install the new version of the app then everything works fine. So I guess that onUpgrade() is never called. What do oldVersion and newVersion refer to? Do I need to specify the version anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLiteOpenHelper has a version argument, if you increment `onUpgrade` should be called:

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
```

For example I have the following class and if I increment `dbVersion` it is called:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase m_Db;

    public DBHelper(Context context, String dbPath, int dbVersion) {

        super(context, dbPath, null, dbVersion);
        ...
        m_Db = getWritableDatabase();
    }
    ...
}
```